# Using a for loop to do this in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a `for` loop in order to formulate this:

- `expand('*+123456')` should return `'1*2+3*4+5*6'`
- `expand('++123')` should return `'1+2+3'`
- `expand('+*1234')` should return `'1+2*3+4'`

A symbol is chosen from the first two characters of the given string in an alternating fashion and placed between the proceeding digits.

Here is what I've been working with:

```
def expand(original):
    var = ""
    symbols = original[0:2]
    for i in range(len(original)):
        var = var + symbols + original[i]
    return var
```

I realize that there also must be a `original[2:]` but I don't know where I can fit this into in here.

I'm an amateur and I've been trying to figure out this question for a long time.

Comment: You got a nice range of answers, all implementing the same solution with different degrees of "pythonicity" - you will learn a lot about python from studying the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your function would be improved by adding `[2:]` in there, but it could also do with losing the `range(len(original))`. Whenever you find yourself writing `range(len(something))`, you should step back and think about what you're actually trying to do.

In this case, you're looking for the characters in the string, and you can get those more straightforwardly with `for x in string`. Here's a slightly improved version, taking those ideas into account:

```
def expand(original):
    var = ""
    symbols = original[:2]
    for digit in original[2:]:
        var += (digit + symbols)
    return var
```

This stops you from getting the weird mixture of symbols at the beginning of the output, but it's still not perfect:

```
>>> expand('+*1234')
'1+*2+*3+*4+*'
```

We need to find a way of

1. taking the symbols alternately, and
2. leaving them off the end of the string.

We can use [itertools.cycle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to handle the first of these, and string slicing for the second:

```
from itertools import cycle

def expand(original):
    var = ""
    symbols = cycle(original[:2])
    for digit in original[2:]:
        var += (digit + next(symbols))
    return var[:-1]
```

That works, but at some point, someone's going to pipe up and tell you you shouldn't use `+` or `+=` to build strings, because it's inefficient. If we build a list instead, and then use `str.join()` to turn that into a string, we can improve things slightly:

```
from itertools import cycle

def expand(original):
    chars = []
    symbols = cycle(original[:2])
    for digit in original[2:]:
        chars.extend([digit, next(symbols)])
    return "".join(chars[:-1])
```

However, we can do better than that. Rather than having to call `next(symbols)` every time, we can use `zip()` to get the next symbol and next digit a pair at a time:

```
from itertools import cycle

def expand(original):
    chars = []
    for symbol, digit in zip(cycle(original[:2]), original[2:]):
        chars.extend([digit, symbol])
    return "".join(chars[:-1])
```

... and that's probably enough :-)

**EDIT**: Since in a comment to another answer, you've said you're not allowed to import anything from the standard library (a rather silly restriction IMO, but there it is), you can use the Python implementation of `cycle()` described at the link earlier in this answer:

```
def cycle(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
            yield element
```

... but you'll probably have to be prepared to convince your teacher that you understand it, which means you need to understand the [yield](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) keyword.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great insight to itertools cycle function. I'm going to have to analyze this for a while.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something along the lines of this:

```
a = "*+123456"

def expand(input):
    symbols = input[:2]
    numbers = input[2:]

    result = ""
    for count, number in enumerate(numbers):
        # Switch symbol for every other iteration
        result += number + symbols[count%2]

    # There's an extra symbol at the end, so remove it.
    return result[:-1]
```

Here's a sample run in the interpreter:

```
>>> a = "*+123456"
>>> def expand(input):
...     symbols = input[:2]
...     numbers = input[2:]
...     result = ""
...     for count, number in enumerate(numbers):
...         result += number + symbols[count%2]
...     return result[:-1]
... 
>>> expand(a)
'1*2+3*4+5*6'
>>> a = "++123456"
>>> expand(a)
'1+2+3+4+5+6'
```

Things to note in the code:

`enumerate` - takes an iterable object and returns a tuple in the form `(index, value)`.

`input[:2]` - Take a slice of the character array from the beginning to the element at position 2 (non-inclusive)

`input[2:]` - Take a slice of the character array from position 2 to the end (inclusive)

`list[:-1]` - Take a slice from the beginning of the list to 1 element from the end of the list.

`count%2` - Take the count (index) of the character in the array and divide it by 2 keeping the remainder. The result of this will change between 0 and 1 every step switching between the two symbols.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to "cycle" over the operator symbols and then interleave ("zip") them with the numbers:

```
import itertools

def expand(original):
    var = ""
    symbols = original[:2]
    numbers = original[2:]
    for symbol, number in zip(numbers[:-1], itertools.cycle(symbols)):
        var += symbol + number
    return var + numbers[-1]
```

This outputs:

```
>>> expand('*+123456')
'1*2+3*4+5*6'
>>> expand('++123')
'1+2+3'
>>> expand('+*1234')
'1+2*3+4'
```

Comment: This is a better solution than my own, but I'm concerned it might be a bit confusing for an amateur.

Comment: @Michael LOL I was thinking exactly the same, that's why I made mine as simple as possible and even avoided the modulo and the enumerate :)

Comment: But +1 for pythonicity anyway.

Comment: yea this must be a good code but I'm not allowed to use import of any kind of build-in function. And yes, it is confusing for me lol

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using a FOR loop as you wanted:

```
def expand(x):

    p=x[:2]
    n=x[2:]
    s=''
    c=0

    for i in n:
       s+=i
       s+=p[c]
       c=1-c

    return s[:-1]
```

The idea is to separate your string into an operator string *p* and a number string *n*, and then iterate through both. The *c* variable changes from 0 to 1 and back, so it constantly iterates over *p* (you can achieve the same with modulo). For more "pythonic" ways of doing this, see the other answers (I was going for amateur clarity).

Comment: Thanks. This was really clearing. I wonder how I would have ever came up with this.

Comment: @Flow it is just a matter of practice. The idea is to try to find the underlying structure of the problem. In this case, you had the correct idea, you were just missing how to iterate over the shorter string. Don't give up...

Comment: @Flow +1 to what Bitwise said. I've found that as I've spent more time on this site seeing what the 'big boys' write, I've completely changed my approach to how I think about things (for the better, I'd like to think :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, every one one here is more useful, but for some reason this piqued my interest:

```
In [9]: from itertools import izip, cycle

In [10]: def expand(s):
   ....:   return ''.join(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, izip(s[2:], cycle(s[:2]))))[:-1]
   ....:

In [11]: expand('*-123')
Out[11]: '1*2-3'

In [12]: expand('+-123456')
Out[12]: '1+2-3+4-5+6'
```

I completely agree with what @Bitwise et al said - definitely not what you're after as it doesn't fit your constraints, so apologies for cluttering the stream :)

For posterity's sake, this takes the string in question, and then uses the `reduce` function to pair a number with one of the alternating symbol strings. We then trim the final symbol and return the `join`'ed result, which will be a string. Hopefully this will be useful in the future!